# GCHandle.FromIntPointer does not work as expected

Tags: c#, mono, clr, .net-4.5

Here's a very simple (complete) program for exercising the use of GCHandle.FromIntPointer:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GCHandleBugTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[10];

            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr pointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            GCHandle handle2 = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this program is essentially a transliteration of the procedure described in English on [CLR via C# (4e)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145353665.do) on page 547.  Running it, however, results in an unmanaged exception like:

`Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x210bc39b, on thread 0x21bc. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.`

Thinking that this might be a bug in .NET 4.5, and since I don't see anything obviously wrong, I tried exactly the same program in Mono on Linux (v2.10.8.1).  I got the slightly more informative but still puzzling exception `GCHandle value belongs to a different domain.`

As far as I am aware, the `handle` really does belong to the same AppDomain as the code where I call `GCHandle.FromIntPtr`.  But the fact that I see an exception in both implementations makes me suspect that I am missing some important detail.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AddrOfPinnedObject` is not the opposite of `FromIntPtr`. You want `ToIntPtr` instead:

```
IntPtr pointer = handle.ToIntPtr ();
GCHandle handle2 = GCHandle.FromIntPtr (pointer);
```

`FromIntPtr` does not take the address of the object, it takes an opaque value (which happens to be defined as IntPtr), which is used to retrieve the object with `ToIntPtr`.

Answer (score 7):

You've got the wrong mental model.  FromIntPtr() can only convert back the value you got from ToIntPtr().  They are convenience methods, handy in particular to store a reference to a managed object (and keep it alive) in unmanaged code.  The [gcroot<> template class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx) relies on it, used in C++ projects.  It is convenient because the unmanaged code only has to store the pointer.

The underlying value, the actual pointer, is called a "handle" but it is really a pointer into a table that the garbage collector maintains.  The table create *extra* references to objects, in addition to the ones that the garbage collector finds.  In essence allowing a managed object to survive even though the program no longer has a valid reference to the object.

GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() returns a completely different pointer, it points to the actual managed object, not the "handle".  The "belongs to a different domain" exception message is understandable since the table I mentioned is associated with an AppDomain.

The crash in .NET 4.5 strongly looks like a bug.  It does perform a test with an internal CLR function called MarshalNative::GCHandleInternalCheckDomain().  The v2 version of the CLR raises an ArgumentException with the message text "Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains.".  But the v4 version crashes inside this method which in turn generates the ExecutionEngineException.  This does *not* look intentional.

Feedback report filed at [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/791096/gchandle-fromintptr-argument-value-check-does-not-work)