# In C#, how do I convert void* (pointing to a managed heap) to an object?

Tags: c#, pointers

I have a `void*` that points to some managed object on the heap.
How do I convert that `void*` value to an `object` (pointing to the same thing, not a copy)?

Note that this is not a duplicate of [C# - How To Convert Object To IntPtr And Back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339928/c-sharp-how-to-convert-object-to-intptr-and-back) because I don't have an output of `GCHandle.ToIntPtr` which can be converted back to `GCHandle` -- I have an actual address of an object.

Comment: See this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/e4y9h1at(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - How To Convert Object To IntPtr And Back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339928/c-sharp-how-to-convert-object-to-intptr-and-back)

Comment: @P.Knowledge Does `GCHandle.FromIntPtr` take a heap pointer? Documentation says "An IntPtr handle to a managed object" -- not sure what it means by IntPtr "handle" -- just a direct pointer?

Comment: @P.Knowledge Hmm, does not seem so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332274/39068.

Comment: Well, as you said, you have a `void*` pointer, right? .NET supports various way of using pointers, like `IntPtr`, which contains raw pointer, to handle in managed environment, and `GCHandle` is a structure to handle unmanaged memory, including pointers.

Comment: This can be help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can convert `void*` to `IntPtr`, however what's the next step? (`IntPtr` to `object`)

Comment: Then use `GCHandle.FromIntPtr(IntPtr)` and get `Target` and cast to appropriate type what you want.

Comment: @P.Knowledge This should not be possible according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332274/39068. _FromIntPtr does not take the address of the object, it takes an opaque value_

Comment: @AndreyShchekin You shouldn't have the address of a managed object unless you pinned it with `GCHandle` (or the equivalent of C++/CLI)... So how did you got this address? Remember that if you didn't pin it, the GC could have moved the object and the `void*` would be pointing to freed memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is wrong on many levels... If the managed object isn't pinned, then it can be moved by the GC whenever it wants, so your `void*` will become illegal.

But you made a question. And I'll give you rope to hang yourself.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ObjectToIntPtr
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public object[] Objects;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr[] Ptrs;
}
```

and then:

```
var array = new int[] { int.MaxValue, 1, 2, 3 };

IntPtr ptr = new ObjectToIntPtr { Objects = new[] { array } }.Ptrs[0];

int[] array2 = (int[])new ObjectToIntPtr { Ptrs = new[] { ptr } }.Objects[0];
```

What you want is the last line. Note that I'm using arrays inside `ObjectToIntPtr` because the .NET runtime doesn't like if I try to do a `struct` with an `object` plus a `IntPtr`, but if they are arrays then there is no problem. `sizeof(object) == sizeof(IntPtr)` so there is no problem even there (the memory used by a `new object[10]` is the same memory used by a `new IntPtr[10]`).

Comment: Nice idea! I might go this way if I don't find anything else.

_What you are trying to do is wrong on many levels..._
I know, and the whole scenario is even weirder, however it's a .NET memory research thing, and not something to power banking or aviation, so should be good.